# Connect socket.io version v2.0 in flutter (Dart) with using web (node js) version v3.0

Tags: flutter, dart, socket.io, socket.io-client

Connection is not establishing with web.

Web version V3 and flutter V2, and also tried disableAutoConnect(), Please help on this, because I am stuck in this, if any further detail needed then let me know

```
 _socket = IO.io(
      'https://app.xxx.com/',
      IO.OptionBuilder().setTransports(['websocket']).
      setQuery({'userId': "64301d3e3663ed0fc3a5b8af"}).build(),
    );


_connectSocket() {
    _socket!.connect();
    _socket!.onConnect((data) => print('Connection established'));
    _socket!.onConnectError((data) => print('Connect Error: $data'));
    _socket!.onDisconnect((data) => print('Socket.IO server disconnected'));
    _socket!.on('chat-list-response', (data) {
      print("receive-message");
      print(data);
      print(data.runtimeType);
      Messages meassge = Messages(
          sId: data['data']['newMessage']['toUserId'],
          ofUser: data['data']['newMessage']['fromUserId'],
          time: data['data']['newMessage']['time'],
          content: data['data']['newMessage']['message']);
      print("meassge");
      setState(() {
        msgDataList!.add(meassge);
      });
    });
  }
```

getting below error:

**Connect Error: WebSocketException: Connection to 'https://app.xxx.com:0/socket.io/?userId=64301d3e3663ed0fc3a5b8af&EIO=4&transport=websocket#' was not upgraded to websocket**